# VSCode IntelliSense proposes a .h file but marks it not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++, include-path

I can't compile a simple stupid demo "project" using visual Studio Code.

As I'm trying to enrich my knowledge portfolio, I trying to learn the basics manually, as to speak I try to compile code manually, without that the Visual Studio Enterprise IDE does all automatically. So I decided to use Visual Studio Code on Mac + clang++ for a simple demo project.

My problem is: I have a Workspace. In this workspace, I have some directories. One Of those directories called Functions and Headers contains again directories: debug, release, include, src. In the `src` directory, I have the `functions.cpp` file containing two dummy methods:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
    return x - y;
}
```

and in the main.cpp:

```
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    int x = add(1, 3);
    int y = subtract(5,1);
    return 0;
}
```

In my `include` folder I have two method declarations:

```
int add(int x, int y);
int subtract(int x, int y);
```

The interesting point is: When I'm in `main.cpp` and I type `#include "` then IntelliSense finds the `functions.h` and proposes that file to me. 
Also, the method calls are highlighted correctly. But: after including the file, Visual Studio Code marks the file read and says: functions.h file not found.

Is that a visual Studio Code bug? Because I also had a look on the settings and the settings seems ok (see picture).

Clang writes:

```
Ginos-MBP:src ginovalentinopensuni$ clang++ functions.cpp main.cpp main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'functions.h' file not found
#include "functions.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.
```

Do I miss something or am I doing something wrong? I also looked at the other similar questions here, but there was nothing helpful.

Pictures:

[image: Settings File]
[image: main.cpp File]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. The VSCode include path that allowed `#include "functions.h"` to be autocompleted has no bearing on what is a valid path to the compiler. There are two ways to address this:

### Fix the path in the source file

Since you are including the header `functions.h` from the `./src` directory, try instead writing:

```
#include "../include/functions.h"

int main()
{
    int x = add(1, 3);
    int y = subtract(5,1);
    return 0;
}
```

This should work. Unless a specific include path is given to the compiler, `clang++`, like most other C++ compilers, will interpret the path relative to the location of the source file. In this case, it needs to go up a directory and then into the `include` directory in order to locate the `functions.h` header file.

### Add an include path to that of `clang++`

From reading the `clang++` man page, it can be ascertained that the `-I` flag may be used to specify an additional include path for the compiler to search to find header files. So, assuming that the command was run from the `./` directory, one jump out of the `src` directory and the root of the project:

```sh
clang++ src/main.cpp -I./include
```

would also address the issue at hand.